# Cosmos DB query fail if parent object is null

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, spring-data-mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am converting  Mongodb to  Cosmos DB without any code change. I use spring-boot-starter-data-mongo api and `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` to select only few fields in document not all fields.

Selecting `_id,address.primary.email,address.primary.secondary` from `emp1` it works fine, if I use the same query select `emp2`, it fails, because `emp2` doesn't have secondary address.

How to fix this issue ?

> Query: { "_id" : { "$in" : ["Emp2"] } }, Fields: { "_id" :
>   1,"address.primary.email":1,"address.secondary.email":1},, Sort: { }

**mongoTemplate.find(query,EmployeeColl.class);**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Emp1",
    "name": "Name1",
    "address": {
      "primary": {
        "email": "eamp1@gmail.com"
      },
      "secondary": {
        "email": "emp1sec@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "Emp2",
    "name": "Name2",
    "address": {
      "primary": {
        "email": "emp2@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  }
]

Exception:
UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 1 and error message

org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2607)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2474)
```

Comment: I heard that you need to message the CosmosDB team to enable a feature flag for `$in`

Comment: @kevinSmith What feature flag do I need to enable ? Can u please provide more information on this

Comment: @Gnana Kevin was referring that it is not supported by cosmos db mongo api maybe, it's not your missing.

Comment: maybe use [spring-data-cosmosdb](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb) for that purpose.